# Element wise multiplication of 2 pandas series containing matrices as elements

Tags: python, pandas, series

Suppose I have 2 pandas series, a and b, where the elements are matrices as follows

```
a = pd.Series([np.array([[1,2], [3,4]]), np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])])

b = pd.Series([np.array([[1,2], [3,4]]), np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])])
```

I would like to multiply the series elements of `a` with `b` such that the output looks like:

[output of series multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0muQx.png)

I have the following solution which works:

```
c = []

for i in range(a.shape[0]):

    c.append(np.matmul(a[i], b[i]))
```

however, this requires a for loop and outputs a list rather than a `.Series`. Any ideas how this could be done in a more compact form? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
c = []

for i in range(a.shape[0]):

    c.append(np.matmul(a[i], b[i]))
    
print (pd.Series(c))

0    [[7, 10], [15, 22]]
1    [[7, 10], [15, 22]]
dtype: object
```

Or:

```
print (pd.Series([np.matmul(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(a.shape[0])]))

0    [[7, 10], [15, 22]]
1    [[7, 10], [15, 22]]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the list to pandas Series and print.
Add the following code at the end:

```
print(pd.Series(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do it in pandas, but it's so much easier if you convert those Series to numpy arrays.

```py
pd.Series(list(np.matmul(np.array(a.to_list()), np.array(b.to_list()))))
```